# Getting actual SQL Query from paramaterized query in C# .NET debugger

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2012, .net-4.5, visual-studio-debugging

I am trying to get the query so I can manipulate it and run it directly in SQL Server. It is a parametrized query like so in my .NET 4+ debugger in VS 2017:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, 
CASE WHEN title = @searchTitle OR fullname = @searchFullName THEN 1 
ELSE ...
AS sorting
ORDER BY sorting ASC;
```

Ignore any syntax issues as the query is a sample and runs fine.  I have the parameters get set correctly too, and as a note, there are tons of actual parameters so me copying and pasting is out of the question.  The query is executed like so:

```
                return this.dataProvider.ExecuteMyLikeQueryTerms(
                     dr =>
                     {
                         var dt = new DataTable();
                         dt.Load(dr);

                         return dt;
                     },
                query,
                parameters,
                connection);
```

How can I get the SQL that is exectured with all the parameters added in so I can see it in the debugger and paste it into SQL Server? I have a very big query and am trying to trace it.

Comment: The parameters *aren't added in*, as in textually replaced - the **parametrized** query is sent to the SQL Server engine "as is", along with the list of parameters and their values.... otherwise it would be wide open to SQL injection attacks again (which is what you're exactly trying to avoid, by using parameters, in the first place)

Comment: As mentioned, the parameter values are *bound* to the parameters in the compiled tree. But you can see a textual *representation* by using the SQL Profiler (RPC:Completed event)

Answer (score 1):

You already have the exact query being sent, which includes parameters (not parameter values). The closest you can get here is to fake some local variables:

```sql
declare @searchTitle nvarchar(max) = N'whatever';
-- etc
```

before your query (which is what MiniProfiler does, to make it possible to copy/paste runnable queries)